# Cut off space between two fields in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I've two fields on account form, one is two option(checkbox) and other is text box. As par my requirements, I've to not show the label of the checkbox but show them as simple fields without caption. I am done with it but stuck in a problem that it create a huge space between two fields, as shown in following screenshot. I would like to hear from your side to resolve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

- Set the **tab** to two columns, settings the first column around 5-10% (experiment with the value)
- put the checkboxes in the first section, the other fields in the second one
- set the first section to have 1 pixels for label width (instead of default 115)

I'm not sure how it would turn out, and would probably need some tweaking (to account for different form/window widths) but you might accomplish something close to what you need.

Another approach would be to build a custom HTML webresource, put it in an IFRAME as the only form element, and rebuild the form from scratch as you like... but it's probably best left as a last-est resort

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the section from 2 columns to 4 columns, span the textbox field to 3 columns. This will reduce the checkbox field columns to 25% and textbox to 75%

This is the maximum we can do in supported way.